# Text dimming routine in python tkinter canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am currently trying to write a [python script](https://github.com/suchindrac/matrix_rain) which streams text similar to [Matrix Rain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rpWrtXyEAN0) using python tkinter module. As per my understanding, Matrix Rain essentially consists of the following:

- Static (not moving) text, which is highlighted character by character
- The first character is highlighted with maximum brightness
- This is followed by the other characters highlighted using decreasing brightness
- The first character keeps moving downwards (along with its characteristics and that of the other characters)
- The text in each line changes (possibly to include the next line) in the next iteration

My current implementation just streams the text on a canvas, but I would like to see if I can get the dimming effect. Is there a python tkinter canvas API that I can use, to get the **dimming effect** on text, as in Matrix Rain?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not. You can change the color of text, but for a dimming effect you'll have to manage all of that yourself.